# Does compiling with `-march=native` bring a measurable performance improvement for mining?

Tags: monerod, mining, compile

I see in [other questions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22-march%3Dnative%22) people are sometimes using this flag, which [enables all instruction subsets supported by the local machine](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html). Does it bring a performance improvement? Are there some benchmarks available to measure this?

Answer (score 3):

Without running any benchmarks to give you hard numbers, yes, it should make a considerable difference. For example, things like hardware AES support will be picked up when compiling with `-march=native` (assuming no runtime checks).